# How can I avoid snoring when not sleeping at home?

Tags: sleep, sleep-deprivation, snore-snoring

I have the nasty habit of snoring quite loudly while sleeping. At home, I have a special pillow that reduces my snoring by about 90%.

Now I am travelling abroad, and forgot my magic pillow. This is leading to serious sleep deprivation for both me and my partner - who is woken up by my snoring despite having earplugs at night. How can I avoid/reduce snoring ? I have **already tried** the following :

- Multiple "anti-snoring" positions,
- Not drinking any alcohol hours before sleeping,
- I have a consistent sleep schedule,
- My nasal passages are not blocked,
- I am not overweight.

I am slowly starting to lose sanity because of sleep deprivation, so it is crucial that I find a way to avoid further snoring.

Comment: What does the pillow do?

Comment: @faustus It elevates my head and provides a "slot" in the middle where my head fits in, thereby minimizing the risk of falling into a snore-prone position.

Comment: I have really bad apnoea and also fit your profile. Essentially the tongue is rolling back into your throat and causing the snoring. Sleeping in the lateral position should help, as would sleeping propped up. I found a great medical device that will not stop vibrating until I am lying on my side. Now, given that you're travelling this is no use to you. I would suggest that the anti-snoring positions do work or at least reduce the snoring, but you're re-positioning yourself in the middle of the night.

Comment: Oh yeah -- to help you sleep on your side, consider getting a body pillow.